# Create a formula from data frame column names

Tags: r, paste, numeric

I'm trying to find a way to format a numeric function, by splitting variables and adding a math operator in between them. Something like

```
y <- data.frame(1:5, 2:6, 3:7,4:8)
names(y) <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

and turn it into a formula that looks like this:

```
~a+b+c+d
```

I tried:

```
x <-c(y)
z <- paste('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', sep='+')
as.numeric(as.character(z))
```

It doesn't work, and I'm pretty sure it's because of the "character" separator I'm using. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Responding to your comments: Put a backtick followed by a tilde followed by a backtick and a open-paren, then your expression, then a close-paren. The formula function will be invoked and you will get a proper formula object. (Why didn't you say you wanted a formula??????????????)

Comment: Yea, I'm sorry about that. I guess I didn't know what I was looking for exactly. I solved my problem just now and I appreciate all of your help. Let me edit my post so others can reference it. I would put down the full answer, but I think Richard would like the credit. I asked him to put down his solution as a distinct answer, so I may mark this as solved.

Answer (score 5):

```
> paste(names(y), collapse='+')
[1] "a+b+c+d"
```

The parameter you were using is `sep`. you should be using the `collapse` parameter. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm looking for an expression, not characters. That's why I [unsuccessfully] tried as.numeric()

Comment: I think you are actually looking for a formula object rather than an R expression. They are both R language objects but not the same class.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close with your second attempt, which would have succeed if you had extracted with "[[" instead of "["

```
> with( y, a+b+c+d)
[1] 10 14 18 22 26
> y[[1]]+y[[2]]+y[[3]]+y[[4]]
[1] 10 14 18 22 26
```

It had nothing to do with the "+"-separator, which is vectorized and that is what you wanted, but in the first case had to do with finding the right function to allow the expression `a+b+c+d` to be evaluated in the proper data environment.

To use your `z` character value you would need to first `parse` it and then evaluate the parsed expression:

```
res = with( y, eval( parse(text= z ) ) )
res
#[1] 10 14 18 22 26
```

For a formula object .... either:

```
 `~`(a+b+c+d)  #  .... or 
#~a + b + c + d

  as.formula("~a+b+c+d")
# ~a + b + c + d
```

If you are convinced that you want just the unquoted letters then (perhaps paradoxically) you can use:

```
quote(a+b)
# returns this at console
a + b
# it is an evaluable object namely a call (since `+` is a function name)

a=5
b=6
eval( quote(a+b) )
#[1] 11
```

Comment: I'm under the impression they are trying to return a call or expression.

Comment: Chris is on the same wavelength as me. I just want the raw expression. The output from Chris' method is: expression(a+b+c+d). But is it possible to have it just be: a+b+c+d?

Comment: @AndrewYueh - That's exactly what the first line in my answer (and also the `cl` line) gives.

Comment: @AndrewYueh: You probably do not want "just:  `a+b+c+d`. That would come from `quote(a+b+c+d)`.From your later comments, you wanted `~a+b+c+d`  (also a language object).... but not `"~a+b+c+d"` which would be a character object.

Answer (score 0):

Building on both answers here...

...if you want the expression:

```
parse(text = paste(names(y), collapse='+')) -> expr
```

...if you want the evaluated results:

```
eval(expr, envir = y)
```

...if you want to learn more: [Non-standard evaluation by Wickham](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html)

Comment: This answers my direct question and I thank you for that. But I guess I should be more specific. The output is expression(a+b+c+d), but is it possible to have it just be a+b+c+d?

Comment: if you literally just want a+b+c+d, you can use quote(a+b+c+d)

Comment: I'm looking for a more 'automated' version of getting to a+b+c+d, which involves reading the table, in one form or another. Your parse() answer is really good, but not quite what I'm looking for

Comment: What are you using it for? In other words, why do you want it to say a + b + c instead of expression(a + b + c)

Comment: I'm using it as part of a formula for neuralnet, in the neuralnet package. The formula layout is output~a+b+c+d, and I want to automate the process by using names from the table.

Comment: @AndrewYueh - If it's for a formula then try `as.formula(c("~", paste(names(y), collapse = "+")))`

Comment: Arggh. If people would only provide enough information! The tilde charcter is actually a function: `<backtick>~(a+b+c+d)<backtick>` returns `~a+b+c+d` which may or may not display properly in an SO comment since  a backtick in R is .

Comment: @RichardScriven That was the exact function I've been looking for. If only I knew as.function() existed... I appreciate everyone's help and I'm sorry about the ambiguity. Turns out I didn't know what I was looking for exactly when I posed this question. Maybe put that down as a formal answer so I may check this inquiry as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer sprintf here because I think more options available.

```
library(magrittr) # for pipes

X <- data.frame(
    x1 = seq(10),
    x2 = seq(10),
    x3 = seq(10),
    x4 = seq(10),
    x5 = seq(10),
    y = seq(10)
)

n = X %>% dplyr::select(-y) %>% names %>% paste0(collapse = " + ")

f <- "y ~ %s - 1" %>% sprintf( n ) %>% as.formula
```